# Are docker images portable across different linux flavours?

Tags: linux, docker, portability

Are docker images portable across different linux flavours? Let's say, if I have OEL based docker image with database installed in it, can I run this in boot2docker on a Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can archive an image ([`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#save)/[`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#load)), copy it on your mac unless your image and run a container in a boot2docker Tiny Core VM.

The only case where an image might not be portable is if its OS filesystem depends on certain patch level of the kernel.
In that case, a container from that image would only run on the right kernel.

[hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992540/are-docker-images-portable-across-different-linux-flavours/29992866?noredirect=1#comment48105768_29992866) that a feature like **[`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)** works only on Linux ([should work on the TinyCore VM of boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/a142bc9a50e443f9a1fe32a004c2d3bff24fab52/kernel_config#L3800)), but would not work when [sharing a folder from the (non-Linux) host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26956623/6309) ([ticket VBox 10660](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1) or [boot2docker PR 284 comment](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/284#issuecomment-50599511)).

Comment: Use docker save and load, not export and import, or you will lose the metadata.

Comment: @AdrianMouat Good point. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: If the application inside docker is using Linux features it will not run on a Mac. For example an application that utilizes `inotify` will work on Linux only.

Comment: @hek2mgl but on Mac, it would run in a Linux Tiny Core VM, no? That Linux is configure to support inotify (https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/a142bc9a50e443f9a1fe32a004c2d3bff24fab52/kernel_config#L3800)

Comment: @hek2mgl I get it: it does not work when sharing a folder from the (non-Linux) host. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Looks my comment was just stupid - having that `boot2docker` thing. Inotify might possibly even work with shared folders, it can, but I don't know how shared folders are implemented actually.

Comment: @hek2mgl no, I think you were right: it doesn't appear to work with shared folder from an non-Linux host.