# Nginx Docker build failing on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker

My Docker build is failing:

```
sudo docker build -t nginx_img_1 .
```

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
```

Why is this not working?

I cannot find the correct location on the http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ website.

When I google for binary-amd64 site: archive.ubuntu.com, I get a broken link.

Background:  I am using an AWS instance of Ubuntu.   I'm trying to build a Docker image with nginx.

Before I tried to do the Docker build, some instructions directed me to enter this line into /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe
```

Other web pages led me to think that the error I am getting can be circumvented by using this line instead in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe
```

This URL and the words after it ("raring main universe") seem to be participating in a dynamically constructed path at the time of the Docker build.  But the error message I got was the same.  So the sources.list file must not be where the problem is.

I'm trying to follow these directions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-and-use-nginx-as-a-proxy

Comment: Why not trying to build your image in a computer where archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ is accessible, and then copy (`docker save`/`docker load`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29992866/6309) your image to the AWS instance?

Comment: Because that is not the problem.  The AWS instance can get there. I did a wget to archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/.  I was hoping someone would know where the archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/ link was being dynamically assembled for the benefit of configuring it and solving the problem.   The website has no "raring" in the archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ folder.